# gitlab-runner giving "invalid value for variable X_PORT" when parsing variables from ci-file

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-runner

I encountered a problem when running `gitlab-runner exec docker ...` for a CI stage that has a section with variables containing ports.

```
    REDIS_HOST: redis
    REDIS_PORT: 6379
    DB_HOST: postgres
    DB_USER: $MYSQL_USER
    DB_PORT: 5432
    DB_SSL: "no"
    DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    DB_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DB
```

The error said `FATAL: invalid value for variable "REDIS_PORT"`. The solution is to simply use quotes around the port numbers.

```
    REDIS_PORT: "6379"
    DB_PORT: "5432"
```

I just wanted to share this simple fix because I could not find it somewhere else.
Note that the `--env` options for the runner do not affect this.